# How to create a trigger function dynamically in pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, triggers, plpgsql

I want to write a pgsql function to create trigger dynamically. For example, a trigger to count insertions in each table. I've tried EXECUTE like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigen(tbl text) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format(
    'CREATE FUNCTION %s_insertCnt() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE insertions SET n = n + 1 WHERE tablename = %s;
    END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql', tbl, quote_nullable(tbl));

    EXECUTE format('CREATE TRIGGER %s_inCnt BEFORE INSERT ON %s
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE %s_insertCnt();', tbl, tbl, tbl);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

But this approach doesn't work. A lot of syntax error occurred when I import this code. It seems that EXECUTE cannot execute a function creation.

What else can I do to create trigger functions dynamically?

Comment: I think the problem is the nested `$$`. To nest dollar-quoted literals, you need to pick different tags. See the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) for details.

Comment: And why would you want to do this? Why dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two $$ sections were getting confused.  By using the $name$ syntax instead you can separate these.

Also the trigger was missing a RETURN.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigen(tbl text) RETURNS void AS $T1$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format(
    'CREATE FUNCTION %s_insertCnt() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $T2$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE insertions SET n = n + 1 WHERE tablename = %s;
        RETURN NEW;
    END
    $T2$ LANGUAGE plpgsql', tbl, quote_nullable(tbl));

    EXECUTE format('CREATE TRIGGER %s_inCnt BEFORE INSERT ON %s
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE %s_insertCnt();', tbl, tbl, tbl);
    END
$T1$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```